# The TeX workflow in LaTeX

Tags: diagrams

I want to draw TeX work flow, but I don't know how to start, any help please?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: This TeX work flow was used in 1990. Now, we are using pdfTeX (or XeTeX or LuaTeX) with direct output to PDF. So, the software with output to the screen is a PDF-viewer. And typically the same software is used for printing documents. Last, but not  least, LaTeX is not only one TeX configuration used for document processing. TeX+another format can be used too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is from an example provided to my students in a LaTeX class (circa 2010-2014)

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}  

% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{blockred} = [rectangle, draw, fill=red!20, 
    text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
    minimum height=2em]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
% Place nodes
    \node [block] (edit) {Edit source with \TeX{}maker};
    \node [blockred, above of=edit] (setup) {Setup for document};
    \node [block, right of=edit, node distance=3cm] (compile) {Compile source};
    \node [block, below of=compile, node distance=3cm] (view) {View output};
    \node [decision, below of=view, node distance=3cm] (decide) {Ready to Print?};
    \node [blockred, right of=decide, node distance=5cm] (print) {Print document};

    \path [line,dashed] (setup) -- (edit);
    \path [line] (edit) -- (compile);
    \path [line] (compile) -- (view);
    \path [line] (view) -- (decide);
    \path [line] (decide) -| node [near start] {no} (edit);
    \path [line] (decide) -- node {yes} (print);
\end{tikzpicture}
\newpage
% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{blockred} = [rectangle, draw, fill=red!20, 
    text width=30em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
    minimum height=2em]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
%% Place nodes
    \node [block] (edit) {Edit *.Rnw with \TeX{}maker and Save};
    \node [blockred, above of=edit, node distance=4cm] (setup) {\LARGE{Setup}\break \footnotesize{New Folder}  \break \footnotesize{Start R, Change dir}    \break \footnotesize{Start \TeX{}maker, Create *.Rnw}   \break \footnotesize{Go to \textbf{R}, Sweave("*.Rnw"), Verify no \textbf{R} errors}   \break \footnotesize{Go to \TeX{}maker}  \break \footnotesize{Compile and View initial output}};
%    
    \node [block, right of=edit, node distance=3cm] (sweave) {With R\break Sweave(" *.Rnw")};
    \node [decision, below of=sweave, node distance=3cm] (rcheck) {Any R errors?};
    \node [block, right of=rcheck, node distance=3cm] (compile) {In \TeX{}maker compile};
   \node [block, below of=compile, node distance=3cm] (view) {View output};
   \node [decision, below of=view, node distance=3cm] (decide) {Ready to Print?};
   \node [block, below of=decide, node distance=3cm] (print) {Print document};
%
    \path [line,dashed] (setup) -- (edit);
    \path [line] (edit) -- (sweave);
    \path [line] (sweave) -- (rcheck);
    \path [line] (rcheck) -- node {no} (compile);
    \path [line] (rcheck) -| node [near start] {yes} (edit);
    \path [line] (compile) -- (view);
    \path [line] (view) -- (decide);
    \path [line] (decide) -| node [near start] {no} (edit);
    \path [line] (decide) -- node {yes} (print);
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the first page output is:

[image]

And the second page:

[image]